# Ola, estava a tentar construir o nome de uma TextBox atraves de uma string. TextBox+index

Tags: c#

```
    private void btnGravarNovosValores_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string descricao;
        string textBoxX;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Object texto in lstTabelaProdutosPreco.Items)
        {
            descricao = texto.ToString();
            i++;
            textBoxX = ("textBox" + i.ToString());

            //MessageBox.Show(descricao + " " + textBox);

            TabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores = new TabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores();
            tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.idTabelaPrecos = Convert.ToInt32(lstNome.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 3));
            tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.idProduto = Convert.ToInt32(descricao.ToString().Substring(0, 4));
            tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.idCalibre = descricao.ToString().Substring(8, 5);
            tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.precoVenda = double.Parse(textBoxX.ToString().Trim());
            if (tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.UpDateDefault())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lstNome.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 3) + descricao.ToString().Substring(0, 4) + descricao.ToString().Substring(8, 5) + textBoxX);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi. Poderia discorrer um pouco mais no corpo da pergunta? Só o título e esse código não me disseram muita coisa

Comment: Consigo construir os nomes das TextBox através de um ciclo textbox +i = textbox1, mas nao consigo usa-la como nome da textbox 
   tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.precoVenda = double.Parse(textBoxX.ToString().Trim());

Comment: "construir os nomes" das textbox ?!?!  tente ser mais claro jovem

Comment: string descricao;
            string textBoxX;

            int i = 0;
            foreach (Object texto in lstTabelaProdutosPreco.Items)
            {
                descricao = texto.ToString();
                i++;
                textBoxX = ("textBox" + i.ToString());
            }

Comment: Você quer acessar um textbox que está no seu form, informando o nome dele em uma string. Isso ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, para começar faça um [tour] e depois veja [ask] e [answer]. Sempre informe [um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel)

Comment: atraves do ciclo foreach consigo a cada volta obter uma  descrição e construir um nome de textbox. quando vou utilizar o nome da textbox

Comment: você só está fazendo a pergunta errada jovem, O que você quer é acessar os TextBox na sua tela de forma dinâmica, dentro do loop. Ou seja, pela string `"textBox"+i.ToString()` voce quer ter acesso ao controle: `string texto =  textBox1.Text;`

Comment: se eu tentar usar o nome criado daigual a textbox (textboxX) em uma messagebox aparece o nome correto, se tentar utilizar o mesmo TextboxX para inserir o conteudo da textbox num banco, da erro "cadeia de carateres de entradacom formato incorreto"

Comment: é isso ,  como faço para que a string seja reconhecida como textbox

Comment: peco desculpa é a 1 vez que estou a utilizar este site e nao sei como fazer as perguntas

Comment: sem problemas, veja se minha resposta ajuda e acesse o tour indicado pelo Everson

Answer (score 3):

Você quer acessar vários `TextBox` que existem no seu Form, de forma dinâmica, dentro do loop.

Para isso você vai utilizar o Método `Find`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx

Exemplo:

```
for (int i =0; i< 10; i++)
{

        Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i.ToString(), true);
        if (controls.Length > 0)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = controls[0] as TextBox;
            if (txtBox != null)
            {
                tabelaAlterarProdutosCalibresValores.precoVenda = txtBox.Text; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
          //não achou o textbox
        }

 }
```

Comment: Resultou Obrigadao

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar como resposta @user9426886